# How to search VS2012 - only in certain file type

Tags: visual-studio-2010

this should be a nice, easy fix for someone.

I want to search for let's say "url"  but I only want to search *.cs files because I don't want the search tool to return all the HTML instances of "url"

I'm sure I was able to do this in previous versions of Visual Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it was indeed a nice easy fix...

Whereas:

Ctrl-F (find) the scope was automatically set to "document".

When you pressed Ctrl-Shift-F, the scope was set to entire solution.

Now - Ctrl-Shift-F brings up "Find in Files"  which is what I wanted.

Comment: Glad that you find it yourself, but you could have done this `little effort` before asking this questions here.

Comment: I'd already done some research, but I just didn't hit the correct search terminology. Once I found the term "Find In Files" it was easy, but remember, Stack Overflow is fantastic for coming up high in the search rankings of google, so if I can save someone else even just 5 mins of their life by them finding this post - then I think it's a good thing - for the user and for StackOverflow.